# How should one use the setState() method in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm trying to understand `state` and `setState()`. Using `setState()` I wanted to change a name, but I am not sure where I should call the `setState()` method in my code:

1. Inside the constructor OR
2. Inside the render method OR
3. Create a custom method and call it at the end of the constructor before `render()` is called

**This is my code:**

```js
import React from "react";

class StateBasic extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        let personProfile =  this.state = {
                name : "Bob",
                skill : "Art Designer",
                location : "LA"
        }
        console.log(personProfile);        
    }

    render(){
        let changeName =  this.setState({ name : "Frank" });

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">   
                <ul>
                    <li> {this.state.name} </li>
                    <li> {this.state.skill} </li>
                    <li> {this.state.location} </li>
                    <li> {changeName} </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default StateBasic;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `setState` in `render()` method you will create infinite loop, instead you can use `componentDidMount`.

```js
class StateBasic extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let personProfile = this.state = {
      name: "Bob",
      skill: "Art Designer",
      location: "LA"
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({name: "Frank"});
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <ul>
          <li> {this.state.name} </li>
          <li> {this.state.skill} </li>
          <li> {this.state.location} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  StateBasic / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` usually occurs (*but it's not restricted to*) when there's some sort of interaction between the user and your application. For example:

- When the user types in an input
- When the user clicks a button

```js
class StateExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      clickTimes: 0,
      value: '',
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ clickTimes: this.state.clickTimes + 1 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Type here:</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click-me</button>
          Click times: {this.state.clickTimes}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StateExample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

For more information I recommend reading [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in ReactJS  docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you initializing the state then do in the constructor

```
constructor(){
    super();
    let personProfile =  this.state = {
            name : "Bob",
            skill : "Art Designer",
            location : "LA"
    }
    console.log(personProfile);
    this.state= { name : "Frank" };//initialvalue         
}
```

If you want to change on some action then make a method (`changeName`) and use like this  in render:

```
changeName(name){
   this.setState({name})
}

render(){

        let changeName =  this.setState({ name : "Frank" });

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">   
                <ul>
                    <li> {this.state.name} </li>
                    <li> {this.state.skill} </li>
                    <li> {this.state.location} </li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeName.bind(this,"hello")} > change Me </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Cyril, thanks for code solution. One question, after test with **this.state= { name : "Frank" };//initialvalue**. I found only **name value Frank** is showing on browser, rest of other values like skill and location are blank. If we use this.state inside of constructor then is it mean it will overwrite all other values of object?

Comment: That was just an example in the constructor you can define the first state... setting the name was just an example. You can define the initial location and skill also. Later you can use setState to override location skill name etc.