# Setting variable data into the react state

Tags: reactjs

I assign some data into variables as below and I can successfully getting values by that.

```
let sno = row.sno;
let uid = row.uid;
```

How can I set those data into the state?

Comment: What is preventing you from using `setState` method ?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109830/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign to the state directly is like

```
let sno = row.sno;
let uid = row.uid;

this.setState({sno:sno,uid:uid})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your data to state by thisState method:

```
this.setState({
"newKey": your_variable,
}
```