# How to conditional comparing with states and values in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, how can I compare the states and values? The values are assigned to the states managerStatus, directorStatus and partnerStatus through componentDidMount(). When I use console.log the values are also retrieved, but when I use the IF condition it doesn't make the change.

```
    console.log(managerStatus);            
    console.log(directorStatus);            
    console.log(partnerStatus); 

    if (managerStatus === "Rejected") {
        this.state.managerStatus = "Pending"
   } else if(directorStatus  === "Rejected")
            this.state.directorStatus = "Pending"
              else if( partnerStatus  === "Rejected")
                this.state.partnerStatus = "Pending"
```

How should the code be corrected?

Comment: Please take a look at, how to update the state is class based [components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109830/how-should-one-use-the-setstate-method-in-reactjs). The way you're updating the state is the not the correct way to update the state.

Comment: I searched but I couldn't get a proper resource. Please can you help me with how it can be corrected?

Comment: im not updating while submitting and not during the rendering process. How can I update in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
    render() {
        const managerStatus = this.state.managerStatus;
        const directorStatus = this.state.directorStatus;
        const partnerStatus = this.state.partnerStatus; 
        if (managerStatus == "Rejected") {
            this.state.managerStatus = "Pending"
       } else if(directorStatus  == "Rejected")
                this.state.directorStatus= "Pending"
                  else if( partnerStatus  == "Rejected")
                    this.state.partnerStatus = "Pending"
}
```

using the above method inside the render() function helped me to solve the problem.The states declared in the constructor above the render() can be accessed via using `this.state.nameofstate`. I accessed them in the render() and then assigned them to variables. Using those variables I compared with the String values and if the condition is true. Using `this.state.statename` the state can be changed.